# Open Excel by VBS and run a macro there

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I need run a VBA macro in Excel but from VBS file. My code for opening Excel file and writing some values is below:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Cells(1,2).Value = "Test value"
WScript.Quit
```

I have 2 simple macros in this file: `test1` and `test2`. I need run them by VBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to put somethink like:

```
objExcel.Application.Run "test1"
```

after

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1.xlsm")
```

an my code will look like:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Run "test1"
objExcel.Application.Run "test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

To run macros from other macros you only have to add these lines to your code... As long as you have saved you macros in the personal sheet the code should look like this... If you have saved them in another sheet, then change the part of the code where it says personal.xlsb for your sheet's name...

```
Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!test1"
Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!test2"
```

Comment: what do you mead about [[globalVariable1], [globalVariable2], ...????
] and why did you wrote  Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!test1" two times???

Comment: I copy pasted... and didn't realise about that duplicated test1...
I guess that you will not need these, so just get rid of them.

Comment: Your code snippet is VBA. To run the macros from VBScript you need to use the application object handle (`objExcel`) instead of the implicit application object that is available in VBA.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working...I pasted it below line 4('objExcel.Cells(1,2).Value = "Test value"') and have alert like:
**"Mistake! you need an object 'Application'"**